# How can I get the "used by" form in Dynamics AX 2009 to work?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, ax

I am trying to do a look up of where labels are used in application objects.

In the label editor there is a button `Used By` which is supposed to perform this function. However, it only ever opens an empty dialog.

Is there some kind of indexing that I need to setup first before this will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to do the update of reference from here:

```
Tools > Development tools > Cross-reference > Periodic > Update.
```

You can read more about this on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877386.aspx

Comment: How long is this supposed to take? This is the fastest machine I've ever had, local AOS and it's taking HOURS to update the cross references.